# How to parse JSON with JAVA when there are random key names

Tags: java, json

How do I convert some JSON to a POJO when I don't know the name of a key?

This is my POJO:

```
public class Summoner {

    private Details summonerDetails;

    public Details getSummonerDetails() {
        return summonerDetails;
    }

    public void setSummonerDetails(Details summonerDetails) {
        this.summonerDetails = summonerDetails;
    }

}
```

The Details class have variables like id, name, etc. -> No issues here

This is the line in my Main class where I try to map the JSON to a POJO:

```
Summoner test = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Summoner.class);
```

this is a JSON response example I receive:

```
{
   "randomName":{
      "id":22600348,
      "name":"Ateuzz",
      "profileIconId":546,
      "summonerLevel":30,
      "revisionDate":1378316614000
   }
}
```

if my POJO Details member variable name is "randomName", above code will work. but when I get a response with a different name than "randomName", it doesn't. How do I make my code work for random names?

I'm using Jackson

I'm sorry I can't make a little more clear my issue.

Comment: You will have to write a custom mapper. How would the default mapper know that you want to do that?

Comment: No idea actually. This is the first time I'm using an API, JSON, JACKSON, etc. Everything is new. I'll do some research on custom mappers, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solution using not only jackson API but with the use of [org.json API](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) also.

```
String str = "{\"randomName\":{\"id\":22600348,\"name\":\"Ateuzz\",\"profileIconId\":546,\"summonerLevel\":30,\"revisionDate\":1378316614000}}";
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
Iterator<?> keys = json.keys();
while(keys.hasNext())
{
    String key = (String)keys.next();
    Details test = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json.getJSONObject(key).toString(), Details.class);

}
```

Here i have use another JAVA Json API to convert your string into jsonObject and than iterate it to get your first key value and map that to your class Details.

I assume that your json format is same as you have mention in your question.

May this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jackson:

```
    String json = "{\"randomName\":{\"id\":22600348,\"name\":\"Ateuzz\",\"profileIconId\":546,\"summonerLevel\":30,\"revisionDate\":1378316614000}}";
    try
    {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map = (Map) new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Map.class);
      for(String key : map.keySet())
      {
          Map<String, Object> submap = map.get(key);
          System.out.println(key + ":");
          for(String k : submap.keySet())
          {
              System.out.println("\t" + k + ": " + submap.get(k));
          }
      }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```